# Why $(this).attr("id") get the old attribute after change it with javascript

Tags: javascript, attributes, attr

I have a weird problem, so after I changed the id of all **table rows** after deleting one row.
Here is a part of my code :

```
$(document).on("click",".fa-trash-alt",function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("id"))
    let index = parseInt($(this).attr("id"))
    globalFunctions.removeFromChoosedList(index)
    $('tr#'+index).remove()
    let rows = $(".choosed-table-data tr")

   $.each(rows,function(index,value){
     $(value).attr("id",index)
   })
  })
```

The problem is that after this operation when I click on a row that should have a new id, the old id appears with `console.log($(this).attr("id"))` despite the id is changed on the inspector

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an example since there is no HTML to relate the js code to. Please edit the question to include the html if you want a more relevant example.

```js
$(".clicked-elm").click((e) => {

    // removes the clicked element
    e.target.remove();
    
    // if you want to remove the children instead do
    e.target.children.forEach(elm => elm.remove());
    
    // not sure what chosen data table is, 
    // but this example should change the id's of each element with that class,
    // unless $() only picks first element. 
    // If so, change it to $$() and it should select all matches.
    $(".choosed-table-data tr").forEach((elm, i) => $(elm).attr("id", i));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this clarification obviously your note was right , i thought my question was but it wasn't .

Answer (score 0):

@Invizi
Thank you for this clarification obviously your note was right , i thought my question was clear but it wasn't .
Anyway i found where i made mistake , as you see , i wanted to get the row's "id" (tr) , which is the parent of the button (".trash-alt") but what i did is:
`$(this).attr("id")` 
where i should do this :
`$(this).parentElement.parentElement.id` 
to move through the parents until i arrive to 
mean : =>=>
i feel i'm idiot XD
finally here is my fixed code

```
  $(document).on("click",".fa-trash-alt",function(e){
    let parent = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
    let index = parent.id
    globalFunctions.removeFromChoosedList(index)
    parent.remove()
    let rows = $(".choosed-table-data tr")

   $.each(rows,function(index,value){
     $(value).attr("id",index)
   })
  })
```